# Matlab Process Memory Leak Over 16 Days

Tags: matlab, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm running a real-time data assimilation program written in Matlab, and there seems to be a slow memory leak. Over the course of about 16 days, the average memory usage has increased by about 40% (see the figure below) from about 1.1GB to 1.5GB. The program loops every 15 minutes, and there is a peak in memory usage for about 30 seconds during the data assimilation step (visible in the figure).

[image: Blue: Matlab process memory usage measured once a second over the course of 16 days. Red: Linear trend in memory usage over time]

At the end of each 15 minute cycle, I'm saving the names, sizes, and types of all variables in the currently active workspace to a .mat file using the `whos` function. There are just over 100 variables, and after running the code for about 16 days, there is no clear trend in the amount of memory used by any of the variables.

Some variables are cleared at the end of each cycle, but some of them are not. I'm also calling `close all` to make sure there are no figures sitting in memory, and I made sure that when I'm writing ASCII files, I always `fclose(fileID)` the file.

I'm stumped...I'm wondering if anyone here has any suggestions about things I should look for or tools that could help track down the issue. Thanks in advance!

Edit, system info:
RHEL 6.8
Matlab R2014b

Comment: Are you opening and closing figures in your actual code? I'd suggest reusing existing figures instead (or maybe at least testing without them). The resultant code may be faster and I recall this sort of thing being a source of memory issues in the past.

Comment: Also, have you tried using the Matlab profiler's [undocumented memory profiling](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/undocumented-profiler-options)?

Comment: Are you writing "pure" matlab?  Or are you accessing mex files, C libraries or java objects from your matlab installation.

Comment: Why are you opening and closing figures for a background application?  I would recommend separating your system into a data collection system, that writes all data read in and pre-processed into a file/DB, then a separate application that allows you to view/access/query the data.  The first should be a very thin application, the second, "thicker" but you don't care if it has memory issues....

Comment: I will try reusing figures instead of clearing them. Also, it sounds like the memory profiling might have issues in linux x64, but I'll try it and get back to you @horchler. Thank you!

Comment: @John, I am using mexed C and Fortran code in the package. Does the matlab thread own the memory used by mexed functions? Because they are called from within a different function, so that memory should be deallocated once the function returns?

Comment: @John, as for your second comment, I agree...the retrospective version of the code (as opposed to the real-time version) does exactly that. It downloads, pre-processes, and assimilates the data in discrete processes. It would be a significant task to break them up for real-time, mostly because timing is particularly important for the real-time implementation. Maybe that will be a last resort :)

Comment: I have never used Linux and Matlab and Mex so I can't help you there.  Do you have strong confidence that there are no memory leaks in your C and/or Fortran code?  You could be not cleaning up a single variable, and get this kind of leak over time.  The very linear nature of your memory growth suggests this type of issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help @John! I hope you don't mind; I included your suggestions in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help @horchler! I hope you don't mind; I included your suggestions in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out the problem. It turns out that the figure handles were hidden, and `close('all')` only works on figures that are visible. I assume they're hidden because the figures are created outside the scope of where I was trying to close the figures. The solution was to replace `close('all')` with `close all hidden`, which closes all figures including those with hidden handles.

I'll go ahead and restate what @John and @horchler mentioned in their comments, in case their suggestions can help people with similar issues:

- Reusing existing figures can increase performance and reduce the potential for memory leaks.
- Matlab has an [undocumented memory profiler](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/undocumented-profiler-options) that could help debug performance related issues.
- For processes that are running indefinitely, it's good practice to separate data collection/processing and product generation (figures etc). The first reads in and processes the data and saves it to a DB or file. The second allows you to "view/access/query" the data.
- If you are calling compiled mex functions in your code, the memory leak could be coming from the Fortran or C/C++ code. Not cleaning up a single variable could cause a leak, and would explain linear memory growth.
- The Matlab function `whos` is great for looking at the size in memory of each variable in the workspace. This can be useful for tracking down which variable is the culprit of a memory leak.

Thanks @John and @horchler!